# Cocos2D 2.1: "Delegate" deprecated in iOS 6. How do I set the delegate for this AVAudioSession?

Tags: delegates, cocos2d-iphone, avaudiosession

Started a Cocos2D 2.1 template (with no physics engine) in Xcode 4.5, targeted for iOS 6 and iPad.  In the CDAudioManager.m file, the following code...

```
AVAudioSession* session = [AVAudioSession sharedInstance];
session.delegate = self;  // Which is what is automatically generated by the template.
```

...generates the following warning...

```
"delegate deprecated:  first deprecated in iOS 6"
```

So I go to the apple developer documentation, and it says under "delegate," "Deprecated in iOS 6.0. Use the notifications described in the Notifications section of this class instead."

http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/AVFoundation/Reference/AVAudioSession_ClassReference/DeprecationAppendix/AppendixADeprecatedAPI.html#//apple_ref/occ/instp/AVAudioSession/delegate

Problem is, it looks to me like all we're trying to do--forgive my inexperience--is set the delegate for the AVAudioSession to the CDAudioManager instance itself.  How do the notifications accomplish this?  Or am I just wrong about the goal of the above code?

Answer (score 16, accepted):

The error you are running into is in this block of code

```
AVAudioSession* session = [AVAudioSession sharedInstance];
session.delegate = self;// <-------- DEPRECATED IN IOS 6.0
```

To silence the warning change those 2 lines to this:

```
[[AVAudioSession sharedInstance] setActive:YES error:nil];
```

Hope this helps.

Comment: Apple deprecated setting the delegate and the AVAudioSessionDelegate protocol in iOS 6 and now you have to listen to the notifications instead through NSNotification center.

Comment: This answer looks incomplete.

Answer (score 11):

**Instead of using delegate use notification for handling as follows**

```
[AVAudioSession sharedInstance];
[[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] addObserver:self selector:@selector(interruption:) name:AVAudioSessionInterruptionNotification object:nil];

 - (void) interruption:(NSNotification*)notification
   {
    NSDictionary *interuptionDict = notification.userInfo;

    NSUInteger interuptionType = (NSUInteger)[interuptionDict valueForKey:AVAudioSessionInterruptionTypeKey];

   if (interuptionType == AVAudioSessionInterruptionTypeBegan)
        [self beginInterruption];

    else if (interuptionType == AVAudioSessionInterruptionTypeEnded)
        [self endInterruption];
}
```

Answer (score 9):

I found a poast about this on the Cocos2D-iPhone.org forums.  While I don't fully understand it--but I'm working on it--it did seem to take care of the problem, at least temporarily.  What he did was write this method in the CDAudioManger.m file:

```
-(void) releaseBufferForFile:(NSString *) filePath {
    int bufferId = [self bufferForFile:filePath create:NO];
    if (bufferId != kCDNoBuffer) {
        [soundEngine unloadBuffer:bufferId];
        [loadedBuffers removeObjectForKey:filePath];
        NSNumber *freedBufferId = [[NSNumber alloc] initWithInt:bufferId];
        [freedBufferId autorelease];
        [freedBuffers addObject:freedBufferId];
    }
}
@end

- (void) interruption:(NSNotification*)notification
{
    NSDictionary *interuptionDict = notification.userInfo;
            NSNumber* interuptionTypeValue = [dict valueForKey:AVAudioSessionInterruptionTypeKey];
    NSUInteger interuptionType = [interuptionTypeValue intValue];

    if (interuptionType == AVAudioSessionInterruptionTypeBegan)
        [self beginInterruption];
#if __CC_PLATFORM_IOS >= 40000
    else if (interuptionType == AVAudioSessionInterruptionTypeEnded)
        [self endInterruptionWithFlags:(NSUInteger)[interuptionDict valueForKey:AVAudioSessionInterruptionOptionKey]];
#else
    else if (interuptionType == AVAudioSessionInterruptionTypeEnded)
        [self endInterruption];
#endif
}
```

Then he replaced:

```
AVAudioSession *session = [AVAudioSession sharedInstance];
session.delegate = self;
```

with this:

```
[AVAudioSession sharedInstance];
[[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] addObserver:self selector:@selector(interruption:) name:AVAudioSessionInterruptionNotification object:nil];
```

Here's the link:  http://www.cocos2d-iphone.org/forum/topic/49956

If and when I develop a better understand of what this code is doing, I'll be sure to edit this post.

Comment: I don't have CDAudioManager.m

Comment: The link you showed also talks about issues with using that new form
the NSNotification center, throws a Bad Access error in that line with iOS 5.0... sooo what would be a concrete solution? they suggest having a iOS version check and throw code accordingly.

Comment: This line is just wrong:  NSUInteger interuptionType = (NSUInteger)[interuptionDict valueForKey:AVAudioSessionInterruptionTypeKey];
It should be     NSNumber* interuptionType = [dict valueForKey:AVAudioSessionInterruptionTypeKey];
    switch ( [interuptionType integerValue] ) {

Comment: `#if __IPHONE_OS_VERSION_MAX_ALLOWED >= 40000
    else if (interuptionType == AVAudioSessionInterruptionTypeEnded) {
        NSNumber *optionsNumber = interuptionDict[AVAudioSessionInterruptionOptionKey];
        AVAudioSessionInterruptionOptions options = [optionsNumber integerValue];
        [self endInterruptionWithFlags:options];
    }
#else`

Answer (score 0):

I haven't tested this but according to this post: http://www.cocos2d-iphone.org/forums/topic/cdaudiomanager-line-402-delegate-is-deprecated/#post-390211

```
float osVersion = [[UIDevice currentDevice].systemVersion floatValue];
if (osVersion >=6.0)
{
[AVAudioSession sharedInstance];
[[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] addObserver:self selector:@selector(interruption:) name:AVAudioSessionInterruptionNotification object:nil];
}
else
{
AVAudioSession* session = [AVAudioSession sharedInstance];
session.delegate = self;
}
```

I.e. throw different code runtime depending on iOS version.

Now, my app is iOS 6.0+ only anyway so I'll just go with:

```
[AVAudioSession sharedInstance];
[[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] addObserver:self selector:@selector(interruption:) name:AVAudioSessionInterruptionNotification object:nil];
```

And cross my thumbs.