# setDelegate deprecated in iOS 6

Tags: xcode, ios7

I am trying to get this sample code running with iOS 7.0 but I am running into some warnings because of deprecated code. The sample code provided [here](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/samplecode/MixerHost/Introduction/Intro.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/DTS40010210) hasn't been updated in 3 years. [Here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13078901/cocos2d-2-1-delegate-deprecated-in-ios-6-how-do-i-set-the-delegate-for-this) is the solution I found which does make sense to me but I am having trouble implementing in the sample code so it will run inside the iOS simulator.

```
AVAudioSession* session = [AVAudioSession sharedInstance];
session.delegate = self;// <-------- DEPRECATED IN IOS 6.0
```

To silence the warning change those 2 lines to this:

```
[[AVAudioSession sharedInstance] setActive:YES error:nil];
```

Someone else suggested

```
[AVAudioSession sharedInstance];
[[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] addObserver:self selector:@selector(interruption:) name:AVAudioSessionInterruptionNotification object:nil];
```

The above solution is a quick fix but I want to get the program running correctly

But all this makes me wonder how do I say function call `setPreferredHardwareSampleRate`  into something that is not deprecated

```
[mySession setPreferredHardwareSampleRate: graphSampleRate
                                    error: &audioSessionError];
```

[image]

Comment: "Use the notifications described in the Notifications section of this class instead."

Comment: I have no idea how to do that

Comment: I'd suggest starting here: https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/Notifications/Introduction/introNotifications.html

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Generally, when a method is deprecated, the headers/documentation are updated with suggestions about what to do instead. Looks like [the documentation in this case](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/AVFoundation/Reference/AVAudioSession_ClassReference/#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40008240-CH1-SW71) suggests [`-setPreferredSampleRate:error:`](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/AVFoundation/Reference/AVAudioSession_ClassReference/Reference/Reference.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40008240-CH1-SW51) as an alternative.

Comment: what does the translated method call statement actually look like in this context?

Comment: Given that the suggested method has the same parameters and return type as the deprecated method it replaces, it will look pretty much exactly the same.

Comment: very new to xcode can you tell me what this should be translated to [mySession setPreferredHardwareSampleRate: graphSampleRate
                                    error: &audioSessionError];